How to avoid bot triggering workflow in GHA
There is a repo that has a submodule, in a workflow triggered by PR it commits and pushes changes to the submodule and after that, the workflow has a step to update the caller repo to get the latest changes in submodule.
Here is the code:
 - name: Checkout submodule repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      repository: submodule_repository
      path: submodule
      token: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      fetch-depth: 0
      persist-credentials: true

  - name: Writes to submodule
    run: |
      python ./main.py

  - name: Push changes to submodule
    working-directory: submodule
    run: |
      git config user.name "name"
      git config user.email "email"
      git add .
      git commit -m "Created or excluded DAG"
      git push

  - name: Checkout caller repo
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      ref:  ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.head_ref || github.ref }}
      path: caller
      token: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      submodules: true

  - name: Update caller repo to latest submodule
    working-directory: caller
    run: |
      git config user.name "name"
      git config user.email "email"
      git submodule update --recursive --remote
      git add .
      git commit -m "Udpated submodule"
      git push

${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }} is a Github App.
The problem is, in the step Update caller repo to latest submodule, when it pushes to the caller repo branch, it triggers the workflow again, creating a loop, that wasn't suppose to happen according to this doc.
You can see the runs below, where the run number 151 was triggered by me creating a PR to main and the 152 was triggered by the push in the step Update caller repo to latest submodule of the run number 151:


This is not quite an answer to your question, but as a work-around you could put a conditional in this workflow to not proceed based on the commit author name or message.

Does this push event sent through the workflow also trigger other workflows in the same repository, or is it just staring this one again and again? If it's just this one, you could add skipping messages to the commit message to skip further workflows to trigger.

My preferred way of handling this is to separate files that are auto-updated from files that are updated by humans. Then the triggers can simply exclude any of the files that are auto-updated.

Hey @TTT, can you formulate your solution as an answer?
I also would prefer to keep separated files, but I didn't get how would you do that.

That was a great idea by @GuiFalourd.
The solution is to add [skip actions] in the commit message:
  - name: Update caller repo to latest submodule
    working-directory: caller
    run: |
      git config user.name "name"
      git config user.email "email"
      git submodule update --recursive --remote
      git add .
      git commit -m "[skip actions] Udpated submodule"
      git push

By the way that is happening because the ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }} is a Github App token, so according to the doc it is right to trigger another run.

I recommend [skip ci] — it's shorter and more universal among different CIs.

Although it's shorter and more universal, for me it can confuse the user, because it will not skip a specific integration as ci or cd, but it will skip any Action that could be triggered by that commit. @phd
